# Circle CI deploy compiled ( generated ) file into Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, babeljs, circleci

I have a nodejs project using Babel. I'm trying compile all es6 files to normal JS files then deploy to Heroku.

But seems the generated file are not deployed.

I try two different configs:

The first one, build after test, then deploy by standard command:

```
test:
  post:
    - yarn build

deployment:
  develop:
    branch: develop
    heroku:
      appname: my-app
```

The second one:

```
deployment:
  develop:
    branch: develop
    commands:
      - "[[ ! -s \"$(git rev-parse --git-dir)/shallow\" ]] || git fetch --unshallow"
      - yarn build
      - git config --global user.email "me@my.com"
      - git config --global user.name "My Name"
      - git commit -am "build"
      - git push git@heroku.com:my-app.git $CIRCLE_SHA1:refs/heads/master
```

But seems not working, the original ( es6 ) files always be deployed into Heroku.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can answer this question by myself now, hopefully can help any one.

```
test:
  post:
    - yarn build
    - git config user.name "My Name"
    - git config user.email "me@my.com"
    - git add -A
    - git commit -m "build"

deployment:
  development:
    branch: develop
    commands:
      - git push -f git@heroku.com:my-app.git ${CIRCLE_BRANCH}:master
```

Comment: I put my name/email values in env vars to keep them out of version control, for privacy